# WinUtils for Spark not working in Windows 11

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried using winutils from multiple sources but it doesn't seem to work on my Windows 11 system both while running Spark-shell and via Java SDK

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe": CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher

Comment: What's your hardware?  Where did you get the binary?  Are you trying to run an ARM binary on an Intel system?

Comment: What is the winutils version you're using ? checkthis repo and use the latest version https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils 
but why installing hadoop on windows ? i think it'll be better to use docker/k8s and play with containers ?